# How to fetch month wise value for below code

Tags: python, calendar, python-holidays

I need to fetch number of holidays for month wise for below code

code

```
import holidays
import calendar

india_holidays = holidays.India ( years=2022 )
#print(india_holidays)

holiday_count_dict = {}

for date, occassion in india_holidays.items ():
    date = str ( date )
    if date[:7] not in holiday_count_dict:
        holiday_count_dict[date[:7]] = 1
    else:
        val = holiday_count_dict[date[:7]]
        holiday_count_dict[date[:7]] = val + 1
 print ( "holiday count : ", holiday_count_dict )
 print(list(holiday_count_dict.values())[0])

 now = datetime.datetime.now ()
 cal = calendar.Calendar ()
 working_days = len ( [x for x in cal.itermonthdays2 ( now.year, now.month ) if x[0] != 0 and x[1] < 5] ) - (list(holiday_count_dict.values())[0])
```

Kindly help me how to resolve it

Comment: @gajendragarg No error in the code... ** working_days = len ( [x for x in cal.itermonthdays2 ( now.year, now.month ) if x[0] != 0 and x[1] < 5] ) - (list(holiday_count_dict.values())[0])**

Comment: i need to fetch records for monthwise holiday

Comment: if I run your code, it gives me this output: holiday count :  {'2022-01': 2, '2022-08': 1, '2022-10': 2, '2022-05': 1, '2022-12': 1, '2022-03': 1}

Comment: Yes,  working_days = len ( [x for x in cal.itermonthdays2 ( now.year, now.month ) if x[0] != 0 and x[1] < 5] ) - (list(holiday_count_dict.values())[0])